# Show that the equation $\frac{1}{2} =4x^3-3x$ has no rational root.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Suppose it has rational root, then $x=\frac{p}{q}$, where $q\neq 0$ and $(p, q)=1$.
Then the equation can be written as,
$$q^3=2(4p^3-3pq^2)$$
So $q$ is even, this force $p$ to be an odd.
So we can substitute $p=2k+1$ and look for any contradiction.
Is the way correct? Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Do you know the “rational root theorem”?

Comment: Nope, ... IDK ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem There are only a very limited number of rational roots that are allowed. It's very feasible to just check them all.

Comment: $8x^3-6x-1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ by the modulo $p$ test for $p=5$. So it has no rational root. Of course, the rational root test is much easier. Are you studying irreducible polynomials right now in your class?

Comment: Ok so the choices for $p=\pm 1$ and $q=\ pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8$??

Comment: You could have continued by making q=2k (an even number) and further observe that regardless wether k is odd or even, p can not be found to be an odd number to satisfy p and q relatively prime.

Comment: In this specific case a trig substitution would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to the equation
$$
8x^3 - 6x -1 = 0 \, .
$$
It states that if $x=p/q$  with integers $p, q$ is a rational solution of that equation then $p$ is a factor of $a_0 = 1$, and $q$ is a factor of $a_3 = 8$.

That gives (a small number of) candidates for rational roots which you can exclude by substituting them into the equation.

Comment: Why factor of $3$?

Comment: @MadhanKumar: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: ok thank you so much

Comment: @MadhanKumar: Note that you were quite close. If you write the equation as $p(8p^2-6pq) = q^3$ then you see that $p$ is a divisor of $1$, and if you write it as $8p^3 = q(6p+q^2)$ then you see that $q$ is a divisor of $8$.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to solve with the rational root theorem and others have already mentioned it. For similar problems, you may be interested also in Eisenstein's criterion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion .
Rewriting your equation as $8x^3 -6x -1 = 0$ you'll see that Eisenstein's criterion is not applicable. we may "fix" that by substituting $x$ by $x+1$. Obtaining:
$$ Q = 8X^3 + 24X^2 - 30X -3$$
Here the prime $p = 3$ satisfies the criterion and as such $Q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ because our shift was an automorphism on $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, Q is irreducible iff $8X^3 -6X -1$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=\frac p q$ with $(p,q)= 1$ and $p>0$. Then you can write $$q^3 = 2p(4p^2-3q^2).$$

This shows that $p | q^3 \implies p=1$, giving $$q^2(q+6)=8.$$

Since $q,q^2|8$ we can only have $q=\pm 1, \pm 2$, but none of them satisfy the last equation.